# Swift OpenGL es enums

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

When using Swift to create an OpenGL app I get this error whenever I use OpenGL commands, for example:

```
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, self.colorRenderBuffer)
```

I get an error '`Int32`' is not convertible to '`Glenum`'

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constants like the ones OpenGL uses are imported in Swift as top-level variable declarations instead of enum declarations.  Because OpenGL doesn't actually use an enum, you'll have to explicitly construct a `GLenum` with `GL_RENDERBUFFER` as its primitive value:

```
glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you think it would be smart of me to develop my OpenGL app in swift? I am afraid that the language is too new and not tested enough.

Comment: The language is mostly stable on that front.  You should be fine.